# Send complete request JSON body in List form

Tags: java, api, rest, rest-assured, rest-assured-jsonpath

I am a beginner in Restassured. I have a PATCH request body which I need to sent in List form as:

```
[{"meal":1434751,"names":["Marisa Kwan","Marisa Kwan"],"quantity":2,"menu_item":163606,"user":45112}]
```

But I am not sure how to send it in required format as mentioned above. My test case code looks like:

```
@Test(dataProvider = "placeBulkOrders", timeOut = 120000)
public void placeBulkOrders(String userID, String names){
    try{
        int user =Integer.parseInt(userID);
        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(map);

        jsonObject.put("meal", 1434751);
        jsonObject.put("names", Arrays.asList(names));
        jsonObject.put("quantity", 2);
        jsonObject.put("menu_item", 163606);
        jsonObject.put("user",user);

        String addData = jsonObject.toJSONString();
        System.out.println("User Data -> " + addData);

        Response response = given().log().all().baseUri(baseURI).
                header("Accept","application/json").
                header("Authorization","Token 055e7wfyr79r8790414f18dbe").accept(ContentType.JSON).body(addData).when().patch(patchOrder).then().log().all().extract().response();

        String responseBody = response.getBody().asString();

        //Assertion for inserted data
        Assert.assertEquals(responseBody.contains("1434751"), true);
        Assert.assertEquals(responseBody.contains(names), true);
        Assert.assertEquals(responseBody.contains("2"), true);
        Assert.assertEquals(responseBody.contains("163606"), true);
        Assert.assertEquals(responseBody.contains(Integer.toString(user)), true);

    }catch (Exception e){
        logger.error("Exception: ", e);
        Assert.fail("Exception thrown. Test Case Failed due to: " + e.getMessage(), e);
    }
}
```

Please help me to send my request body in required format.

Answer (score 0):

What is stopping you from using JSON files as data?

You could have a function that reads the JSON file as a string:

```
protected static String LoadJsonFileAsString(String jsonFileName) throws IOException{
    // This will load a file; give complete path.
    return new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(jsonFileName)));
}
```

Then you can have a code such as the following:

```
    String endpoint = "theUrl.com/endpoint";

    String rawData = LoadJsonFileAsString("path/to/json/file");

    Response resp = given()
            .header("header1Key", header1Value)
            .header("header2Key", header2Value)
            .contentType("application/json")
            .body(rawData)
            .when()
            .patch(Endpoint)
            .then()
            .extract().response();

    Assertions.assertEquals(200, resp.statusCode());
```

If you need to update a JSON file through iteration, you can use something like the following:

```
protected static void UpdateJsonFileUserIDAndName(String jsonFileName, String userID, String name) throws IOException, JSONException{
    DocumentContext doc = jsonPath.parse(LoadJsonFileAsString(jsonFileName));
    doc.set("$.path.to.userID", userID);
    doc.set("$.path.to.name", name);
    String newJson = doc.jsonString();

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.configure(JsonParser.Feature.ALLOW_UNQUOTED_FIELD_NAMES, true);
    Object json = mapper.readValue(newJson, Object.class);
    String indented = mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(json);

    try (FileWriter file = new FileWriter("src/test/java/com/path/to/file.json")) 
        {
            file.write(indented);
    }   

}
```

where `jsonPath` is `com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath jsonPath`. `DocumentContext` also comes from there. You might need to import it in your pom file if you have one.

You might have a tough time to learning how to find the proper doc path, as I did when I did it for the first time. A thing you can use is an online web tool called [jsonpath](https://jsonpath.com) .

You're almost there.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @RemusM. But the problem is I am reading data from an XLSX file and building the JSON body. Your way is good enough if I have limited JSON body to send as request body. I am not sure how I can use it for bulk data.

Comment: @Saurabh I am not quite sure I understand. Are you hoping to use one, multiple, or all XLSX rows from a single xlsx file for one request? I could try to investigate this, and see how to convert xlsx to json

Comment: My xlsx file contains 2 cols - UserID & Name (for respective UserID) and has more than 1000 users. I am trying to place an order for each user with 2 quantities as you can see in my Expected request body structure above. In order to do this, I have to read each UserID and Name from my XLSX file row by row and build a request body every time.

Comment: @Saurabh My first solution in mind would be to make a sample json file, have a for loop for the length of the XLSX, save the columns as strings, and then with every iteration, update the json file at every iteration, and make the call. I will update my solution to include a way to update a json file.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76005654/send-complete-request-json-body-in-list-form#comment134080277_76008420) comment, you have an issue with retrieving data from xlsx file. You should be able to get it done from `dataProvider`.

Please find the following answer for the issue mentioned in the original question. You can use `jackson objectmapper` to get your work done.

Even though you have mentioned the parameter as `names` in the method name (`placeBulkOrders(String userID, String names)`) , I assume only a single name is received from the dataProvider. (Eg:- "Marisa Kwan")

```
@Test(dataProvider = "placeBulkOrders", timeOut = 120000)
public void placeBulkOrders(String userID, String name){
    try{

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        ObjectNode template = null;

        try {
            template = (ObjectNode) mapper.readTree("{\n" +
                "  \"meal\": 1434751,\n" +
                "  \"names\": [\n" +
                "    \"Marisa Kwan\",\n" +
                "    \"Marisa Kwan\"\n" +
                "  ],\n" +
                "  \"quantity\": 2,\n" +
                "  \"menu_item\": 163606,\n" +
                "  \"user\": 45112\n" +
                "}");
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        ObjectNode jsonBody = template.deepCopy();

        // Adding the userID to the jsonBody
        jsonBody.put("user", userID);

        // Creating the names list
        List<String> namesList = new ArrayList<>();
        namesList.add(name);
        namesList.add(name);

        // Convert the namesList to ArrayNode and adding into the names array
        ArrayNode arrayNode = mapper.valueToTree(namesList);
        jsonBody.put("names", arrayNode);

        // Add the jsonBody to a array
        ArrayNode finalArrayNode = mapper.createArrayNode().add(jsonBody);

        System.out.println("User Data -> " + finalArrayNode);

        Response response = given().log().all().baseUri(baseURI)
                .header("Accept","application/json")
                .header("Authorization","Token 055e7wfyr79r8790414f18dbe")
                .accept(ContentType.JSON)
                .body(finalArrayNode)
                .when()
                .patch(patchOrder)
                .then().log().all().extract().response();

        String responseBody = response.getBody().asString();

        //Assertion for inserted data
        Assert.assertEquals(responseBody.contains("1434751"), true);
        Assert.assertEquals(responseBody.contains(names), true);
        Assert.assertEquals(responseBody.contains("2"), true);
        Assert.assertEquals(responseBody.contains("163606"), true);
        Assert.assertEquals(responseBody.contains(Integer.toString(user)), true);

    }catch (Exception e){
        logger.error("Exception: ", e);
        Assert.fail("Exception thrown. Test Case Failed due to: " + e.getMessage(), e);
    }
}
```

Please find the relevant imports below;

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ArrayNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode;
```